# Не работает Skype при работающем AppServ

Tags: apache, skype

Как мне уладить проблему: при работающем AppServ не работает Skype?
То, что Skype использует 80 порт для дополнительных соединений, я знаю. Если убрать галочку, то он тоже глючит, хотя меньше )
Есть идея поменять порт в `httpd.conf`, но нигде такого решения не видел. Скайп отключать не могу, поскольку должен быть на связи.
Может кто-то сталкивался с проблемой работы двух приложений одновременно?

Comment: в httpd.conf порт поменять можно. Поищите внимательно. А скайп лучше снести. Тогда никаких проблем не будет, Но если он очень сильно нужен - используйте вебскайп - web.skype.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала надо зайти в скайп и отключить использование 80 и 443 портов:

```
Инструменты - Настройки - Дополнительно - Соединение:
```

> Для дополнительных входящих соединений следует использовать порты 80 и 443

---

Если вышеописаный метод не помогает, то надо редактировать файлы конфигураций.

В файле `httpd.conf` надо заменить 80 порт на какой-то другой, например, 8080 :

```
Listen 80
ServerName localhost:80
```

Также потребуется сделать аналогичные изменения в файле `httpd-ssl.conf` :

```
Listen 443
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
ServerName www.example.com:443
```